# How do you add a second test for a function when using GNAT test?

Tags: unit-testing, ada, gnat, aunit

The [documentation for Gnat](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.3/gnat_ugn_unw/Creating-Unit-Tests-Using-gnattest.html#Creating-Unit-Tests-Using-gnattest) test shows how to generate a harness and skeleton unit tests. It creates one unit test for each public function in the target project, but if I add another this gets overwritten when I regenerate the harness and skeleton unit tests.

In the [simple example](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.3/gnat_ugn_unw/Simple-Example.html#Simple-Example) project provided with gnattest, how do I add another test? I've tried:

(1) Adding another Assert line to the test function that is already there. This works but is not good practice; the first test to fail prevents the others from being run.

(2) Adding a function definition to obj/gnattest/harness/gnattest.xml and then [regenerating the tests](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.3/gnat_ugn_unw/Regenerating-Tests.html#Regenerating-Tests) does not work; the xml file is regenerated before it is used to create the test stubs.

(3) Adding the definition to tests/ and harness/ manually by the changes below, which get clobbered by regenerating tests.

Add this to obj/gnattest/tests/simple-test_data-tests.ads:

```
   procedure Test_Inc2_4f8b9f (Gnattest_T : in out Test);
```

Add this to obj/gnattest/tests/simple-test_data-tests.adb:

```
--  begin read only
   procedure Test_Inc2 (Gnattest_T : in out Test);
   procedure Test_Inc2_4f8b9f (Gnattest_T : in out Test) renames Test_Inc2;
--  id:2.2/4f8b9f38b0ce8c74/Inc/1/0/
   procedure Test_Inc2 (Gnattest_T : in out Test) is
   --  simple.ads:7:4:Inc
--  end read only
   begin
     Assert (Inc(2) = 2, "this test should fail");
--  begin read only
   end Test_Inc2;
--  end read only
```

Add the declaration to line 16 and the create and add_test to the Suite function in obj/gnattest/harness/simple-test_data-tests-suite.adb:

```
   Case_1_1_Test_Inc2_4f8b9f : aliased Runner_1.Test_Case;

  Runner_1.Create
    (Case_1_1_Test_Inc2_4f8b9f,
     "simple2.ads:7:4:",
     Test_Inc2_4f8b9f'Access);
  Result.Add_Test (Case_1_1_Test_Inc2_4f8b9f'Access);
```

To recompile, don't use the Makefile, as that will clobber the changes. Instead, run

```
gprbuild -Pobj/gnattest/harness/test_driver.gpr
./obj/gnattest/harness/test_runner.exe`.
```

There has got to be a better way.

Comment: Instead of another `Assert` line, can you expand the `Check` predicate, e.g. `Assert(relation or relation), …`?

Comment: That's even worse than using two asserts, because then the Assert message doesn't even distinguish between the two things that could have gone wrong.

Comment: I'd expect the message to reflect the chosen logical operator. Would _§5.10.13. Additional Tests_ offer a suitable alternative?

Comment: Since additional tests are handwritten, you cannot regenerate the harness and skeleton unit tests automatically, which is what I am looking for. When I add a new function to the production code, I expect the unit test skeleton(s) to be generated, leaving the original testcode as-is.

Comment: A note; I simply stopped using gnat test and once I understood how to use AUnit properly and never looked back. I don't really know why you would want unit test skeletons to be written for you; there shouldn't be boilerplate code when your test framework is set up correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a GNAT-specific pragma or aspect (Ada 2012), if you don't mind modifying the test subject (and losing a bit of portability in the process...)

I'll show the syntax for pragma first, the rest of the examples will use aspect syntax:

```
function Foo(Bar : in Integer) return Integer;
pragma Test_Case("Test 1", Robustness);
```

Same example with aspect syntax:

```
function Foo(Bar : in Integer) return Integer
   with Test_Case => ("Test 1", Robustness);
```

Or if you like named association:

```
function Foo(Bar : in Integer) return Integer
   with Test_Case => (Name => "Test 1", Mode => Robustness);
```

This will generate additional wrapper code as well as a test case, which may seem like clutter, unless you specify `Mode => Nominal` (see below) or any of the two optional parameters, `Requires` and `Ensures`:

```
function Foo(Bar : in Integer) return Integer
   with Test_Case => (Name => "Test 1", 
                      Mode => Robustness,
                      Requires => Bar < 10,
                      Ensures => Foo'Result > 15);
```

`Requires` acts as a test case-specific pre-condition,
while `Ensures` acts as a test case-specific post-condition, 
which will be checked by the generated wrapper code.
If you have existing `Pre` or `Post`-conditions on the test subject, the generated code can check these as well, if you specify `Mode => Nominal`. (they will be ignored when using `Mode => Robustness`).

```
function Foo(Bar : in Integer) return Integer
   with Pre => Bar > 5,
        Post => Foo'Result < 10,
        Test_Case => (Name => "Test 1", 
                      Mode => Nominal,
                      Requires => Bar < 10,
                      Ensures => Foo'Result > 15);
```

And of course, you can add more than one `Test_Case`:

```
function Foo(Bar : in Integer) return Integer
   with Test_Case => ("Test 1", Robustness),
        Test_Case => ("High Bar", Robustness),
        Test_Case => ("Low Bar", Robustness),
        Test_Case => ("Candy Bar", Robustness);
```